# Location Manager Not working

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple android application to determine the current location by the GPS but when i run the app on my phone it just gives me the accuracy without giving the real coordinates Here's My Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    v1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    v2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    v3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    int GpsUpdateInterval = 60 * 1000; 
    int GpsUpdateRadius = 15;

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            GpsUpdateInterval, GpsUpdateRadius, new LocationListener() {

        @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle exras) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // this function trigger when a new location founded
                    v1.setText("Lat "
                            + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                    v2.setText("Lng "
                            + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                    v3.setText("Accurcy "
                            + String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));

                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
v2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
v3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

You have bad view bindings ;)

Comment: Aha Thank you , but could you please check the rest of the code if its right or not

Comment: Yes, is perfectly fine